# Reset Outlook 2010 calendar view

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

After doing a calendar search in Outlook 2010, every time I open my calendar it opens with that search result.  It takes me 8 or 10 more clicks to get back to my calendar which always opened when I clicked on calendar prior to the fateful search.  How can I get back to that state?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset **all** views with the /cleanviews switch or create a custom view for the Calendar with Manage Views.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-outlook-2010-HP010354956.aspx

http://www.outlook-tips.net/beginner-user/reset-the-view-in-outlook/